# When composer connects to GitHub I receive a warning about a deprecation authentication method. What authentication configuration should I use?

Tags: php, github, composer-php

GitHub has started sending emails about deprecated authentication but I have not yet found a resource for detailing what composer's `auth.json` should look like under the new regime.

My requirements are relatively simple - using composer to update a Symfony application in development and occasionally experimenting with other repos.

With this, my original configuration (automatically built)...

```
{
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "(a string)"
    }
}
```

... I receive this warning:

> ...your personal access token...was used as part of a query parameter
>   to access an endpoint through the GitHub API...Please use the
>   Authorization HTTP header instead...

But when I try with this other configuration:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "github.com": {
            "username": " my email address",
            "password": " my password "
        }    }
}
```

I receive this other warning:

> You recently used a password to access an endpoint through the GitHub
>   API using Composer/1.9.1 ...We recommend using a personal access token
>   (PAT) with the appropriate scope to access this endpoint instead.

What should it really look like and why am I getting these deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of these two configurations, the first is the correct one.

The "string" should be your Personal Access Token (PAT), configured with the [appropriate access scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/) on GitHub.

To configure the scopes for your token you need to visit your GitHub Developer Settings -> [Personal Access Tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens/).

The second format attempts to authenticate sending your username and password instead of a generated token. That's **a bad security practice**, and should not be done.

But the main reason you are getting the first warning is because **you are running an old composer version**.

You need to **update to the 1.9.3 version**, [where this was fixed](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8586#issuecomment-583276576). On previous versions you may get the deprecation warning nonetheless because of how composer connects to GitHub.

Comment: Yet when I use a personal access token to update one of my Symfony projects I get the `use the Authorization HTTP header instead` email.

Comment: @geo How is your repository defined? What's its `type`?  `vcs`? `git`? `github`?

Comment: `composer.json` only has `"type": "project"`. None of the other elements you mention. This is true for each project.

Comment: Ok, I thought you had defined a private repository. Then check the edited answer, you need to update composer to the latest version. If you still get the warning, delete `composer.lock` and reinstall, since sometimes there are cached urls in the lock file.

Answer (score 2):

Update composer and the error will disappear

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

or

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer. There's already an accepted and pretty good explained answer, and by adding another one, you should provide some more insights